# Virtocommerce - Add comment to the list?

Tags: virtocommerce

Can we replace the User ID with the Comment value? The User ID should be in the detail page, but it would be handy to see the comment from the overview page!
see this pic:https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQkx0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comment value / field are you referring to?

We are currently working on allowing customization of list with custom/selected properties as well as a new web based management console. So your feedback is very useful to us.